Resolve merge conflicts when rebasing without manual intervention
Let's have a file readme.txt and such a branch structure
master
  |
branch_a 
  |
branch_b

How this structure is organized:

When we are in master:
git checkout -b branch_a
echo "a" >> readme.txt
git add .
git commit -am "a"


 
git checkout -b branch_b
echo "b" >> readme.txt
git add .
git commit -am "b"



Right now what we are in branch_b and we have in readme.txt:
a
b

Now, I'd like to make adjustment to readme.txt in branch_a. First, switch to branch_a:
git checkout branch_a

Then edit readme.txt like this:
a_1

Then I'd like to switch to branch_b, merge with branch_a and preserve the adjustments made in branch_a.
In other words, I'd like to run some commands so that in branch_b in readme.txt I would have:
a_1
b

The key point is it should be done by commands. How can this be done without interference of a person to resolve a conflict?

You cannot, it's the whole point of conflicts. If it were that easy, Git would already have a solution.

That said, if this is a situation that occurs predictably in an automated environment and the conflicts always have the same shape and must be resolved in the same manner, you may be able to write a merge driver that resolves this particular conflict.

You'll have to resort to using something other than git for this scenario.
For example, knowing that you only want the first line of the file on one branch and all but the first line for the file on the other branch:
$ git checkout branch_b
$ printf "%s\n%s\n" $(git show branch_a:readme.txt | head -n 1) $(tail -n+2 readme.txt )
a_1
b


No, it is not that predictable. What is predictable is that the branch that should prevail is always known. And it is always the predecessor.

@Kifsif Whether it's predictable or not, you can't use git for this. You'll have to use an approach similar to what I showed.
